# Is it possible to increment function pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have the following code where I get segmentation fault as the my function pointer is pointing to an an array of function pointer and after increment of the function pointer is not pointing to the next element in the array of function pointers.

```
int f2(int);
int f1(int);
int(*fp[2])(int) = {f1,f2};

int f1(int x)
{
return (x+10);
}


int f2(int y)
{
return (y+20);
}

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    int (*fp1) (int);

    fp1 = fp;
    printf("addr of fp1 is %x\n",fp1);
    ++(fp1);
    printf("after increment addr of fp1 is %x\n",fp1);
    sum = (*fp1)(sum);
        printf("%d \n",sum);
        return 0;
    }
```

But when I use pointer to pointer to function pointer like:

int (**fp1) (int);
then the code works fine.
Please tell:

1- why just pointer to function is not working.

2- pointer to function i.e. fp1 incrementing the address by one only when doing  ++fp1.

3- when I am passing fp1 = fp[0]; then also it is not working with both the pointer to pointer to function .. and also with pointer to function. Are fp and fp[0] pointing at different addresses?

Comment: Even if it is possible, it yields undefined behavior. So you should avoid doing that.

Comment: Your program compiles with warnings. Up your warning level to the max and fix them all. It makes no sense to even start talking about a program with warnings.

Comment: @nm Depending on the types of warnings. A correct program can give "might be used uninitialized" and "comparing signed and unsigned" warnings, though of course they're avoidable.

Comment: @n.m.: With Visual Studio you want one less than the max.  With warnings at max in Visual Studio, the provided standard library produces a great many warnings.  Even at level 3 out of 4, `<chrono>` line 749 in VC2013 contains a implicit conversion from `__int64` to `int`, regardless of template parameters.

Comment: @Mayank (1) you are mistaken. which compiler are you using? what is your compilation command? (2) there are no such thing as ignorable warning. fix them **ALL**.

Comment: @MooingDuck this is C, not C++, but if max-1 works for VS, more power to Microsoft...

Comment: @n.m.: `void f(int var) { if (var > 100) throw std::runtime_error(); if (var < 50u) throw std::logic_error();} ` provides a completely pointless warning.  Requiring to fix it is an opinion thing.   (oh, it is C.  eh, the C libraries probably have warnings too)

Comment: @MooingDuck to me, this code happily provides `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::runtime_error::runtime_error()`, which is a good thing, because `std::runtime_error` [has no default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error). Your compiler is just broken, write to your vendor and demand a fix. Anyway, you should fix every warning, even the most pointless ones, because if you routinely allow warnings, you might miss one which is not pointless.

Comment: @n.m. MSVC compilation with `/Wall` results in warnings from the standard headers such as `<stdio.h>`. Fixing them would mean modifying the vendor's headers, possibly introducing incompatibilities or even breaking inline functions because the behavior resulting from the code wasn't understood. Compiling with `/W3` seems to work better. This has happened in multiple releases, and I'm not sure they will be fixed. The usual answer has the tone of, "These are warnings, not errors."

Answer (score 5):

**Pointers to functions**

The increment and decrement operators are not valid for pointers to functions.

Here's the relevant text from the C++ Draft Standard (N3337):

> **5.3.2 Increment and decrement**
>
> 1 The operand of prefix `++` is modified by adding `1`, or set to `true` if it is `bool` (this use is deprecated). The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a completely-defined object type. The value is the new value of the operand; it is an lvalue. If `x` is not of type `bool`, the expression `++x` is equivalent to `x+=1`.

The type of a pointer to a function is neither an arithmetic type nor is such a pointer a pointer to a completely-defined object type. Hence, `++` cannot be applied to a pointer to a function.

As far C is concerned, the C99 Standard (n1256) says:

> **6.5.3.1 Prefix increment and decrement operators**
>
> 1 The operand of the prefix increment or decrement operator shall have qualified or unqualified real or pointer type and shall be a modifiable lvalue.
>
> 2 The value of the operand of the prefix ++ operator is incremented. The result is the new value of the operand after incrementation. The expression ++E is equivalent to (E+=1). See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for information on constraints, types, side effects, and conversions and the effects of operations on pointers.

and

> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
>
> 2 For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

Here again, a pointer to a function cannot be incremented for the same reasons.

**Array of pointers to functions / Pointers to pointers to functions**

The line

```
int(*fp[2])(int) = {f1,f2};
```

declares an array of pointers to functions. Hence, the expressions `fp[0]` and `fp[1]` are valid expressions. You can have a pointer to a pointer to function object that be used with the increment operator.

```
int (**fpp)(int) = fp;
(*fpp)(10);  // Calls f1(10)
fpp[0](10);  // Calls f1(10)
fpp[1](10);  // Calls f2(10)
++fpp;
(*fpp)(20);  // Calls f2(20)
fpp[0](20);  // Calls f2(20)
```

Unfortunately, gcc 4.7.3 allows the following statements to compile while g++ does not.

```
int(*fp[2])(int) = {f1,f2};
int (*fpp)(int) = fp;
```

Calling

```
fpp(10);
```

leads to undefined behavior in such a case.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++. This mostly doesn't matter, but in C the erroneous code `fp1 = fp` passes compilation (with a warning), while in C++ it's illegal, so you might want to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

`fp1` is defined as `int (*fp1) (int);` this is **NOT** a pointer to a function pointer array. It's a pointer to a function. You **can't** increment it.

However you can/should increment a pointer to an element of your array:

```c
int (**fp_array)(int) = fp;

fp1 = *fp_array;
printf("addr of fp1 is %x\n",fp1);
fp1 = *(++fp_array);
printf("after increment addr of fp1 is %x\n",fp1);
```

But in this case, it's nonsense, why not simply write:

```c
fp1 = fp[0];
printf("addr of fp1 is %x\n",fp1);
fp1 = fp[1];
printf("after `increment` addr of fp1 is %x\n",fp1);
```

Comment: `fp` isn't an array pointer it's an array of pointers. You can't increment arrays.

Comment: That's not an array pointer. An array pointer would be a pointer to an array; `fp` is an array of pointers to functions.

Comment: When I am using pointer  to pointer to function then increment is working fine. But it also  fails with segmentation fault when I use fp1 = fp[0]; in place of fp1=fp;

Comment: @d3l I made some fixes to your wording; I hope it's better now - otherwise, revert them

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the given responses, which already answer your problem, I'd like to suggest that you typedef the function type:

```
typedef int function(int);
function* fp[] = { &f1, &f2};
function** f = fp; // array-to-pointer decay
```

`f` can now be incremented the way that you expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you try to do is possible. However, it is obviously tricky or you wouldn't be posting here.

Much simpler to use an index into the array fp.

```
int i = 0;
printf ("First result = %d\n", (* (fp [i++])) (10));
printf ("Second result = %d\n", (* (fp [i++])) (10));
```

That way someone reading the code has a chance to figure out what it does.